# If you use bootstrap 5 icon in star rating then there is problem of half star

Tags: rating, review

If you use bootstrap 5 icon in star rating then there is problem of half star

**CSS**

```
/* The star of the show */
.rate > label:before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: .3rem .2rem;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: FontAwesome; /* I want to use bootstrap-icons */
    content: "\f005 "; /* full star */
}

/* Half star trick */
.rate .half:before {
    content: "\f089 "; /* half star no outline */
    position: absolute;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<i class="bi bi-star-half"></i>
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't understand your question... can you elaborate more?

Comment: .rate > label:before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: .3rem .2rem;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: FontAwesome; /* I want to use here bootstrap-icons */
    content: "\f005 "; /* full star */
}

/* Half star trick */
.rate .half:before {
    content: "\f089 "; /* half star no outline */
    position: absolute;
    padding-right: 0;
}

 I want to use here bootstrap-icons */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `FontAwesome` Icons then problem is solved

Comment: looks like a rough ad to me